# asp.net js controlID increase dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, textbox

I want to increase ASP controlID each time I click button. Like adding more phone numbers. Each time new asp:textbox is added, new ID should be created. 
Adding more div/textbox is working fine, but ID of each textbox is same.

```js
function GetDynamicMobileNo(value) {
        return '<div><asp:TextBox ID="txtAddMoreNumber" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="11" Placeholder="Mobile No"></asp:TextBox></div></br>';
    }
  
    function AddMobileNo() {        
        var div = document.createElement('DIV');
        div.innerHTML = GetDynamicMobileNo("");
        document.getElementById("MobileNoContainer").appendChild(div);
      
    }
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: You can't add server side control like `<asp:TextBox ID="txtAddMoreNumber" runat="server"/>` in JavaScript. It added to html but it doesn't work because It will not be rendered in client side.

Answer (score 1):

Id is same because you are generating html with the same Id.

```
//Here is your problem
function GetDynamicMobileNo(value) {
        return '<div><asp:TextBox ID="txtAddMoreNumber" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="11" Placeholder="Mobile No"></asp:TextBox></div></br>';
    }

    function AddMobileNo() {        
        var div = document.createElement('DIV');
        div.innerHTML = GetDynamicMobileNo("");
        document.getElementById("MobileNoContainer").appendChild(div);

    }
```

Change it to this code

```
function GetDynamicMobileNo(value, id) {
        return "<div><asp:TextBox ID=\" + id + \" runat=\"server\" CssClass=\"form-control\" MaxLength=\"11\" Placeholder=\"Mobile No\"></asp:TextBox></div></br>";
    }

    function AddMobileNo() {        
        var div = document.createElement('DIV');
        div.innerHTML = GetDynamicMobileNo("", someRandomIdGenerator());
        document.getElementById("MobileNoContainer").appendChild(div);

    }
```

Comment: I was going to answer something similar :p

Comment: @TusharShukla Sure you can :)

Comment: I tried as you said. It says " '+ id + '" is not a valid identifier.

Comment: @Hey24sheep i tried, now the new problem is that it says "the server tag isn't well formed."

Comment: are you trying to add this in .aspx file? and if so why dont you add your textbox using cs file.

Comment: because it will postback. I m trying in .aspx file with JS.

Comment: why don't you use normal <textbox></textbox>? and do the postback call in your js